# Receive response with request in node.js

Tags: node.js, callback, request

I need to recover the response in variable and show it

```
'confirmation' :()=> {
         let responseJson = {};
        var request = require('request');
        var url = 'http://dev.exemple02.com/ws/ws_login_sh.php?username=' + username + '&password=' + password;
        request(url, function (error, responseJson, body) {
            console.log(responseJson);
            var test = JSON.parse(body);
            if(test['codeRetour']===1){

                var customer=test['customer'];
                var nom=customer['first_name'];
                var prenom=customer['last_name'];
                console.log('super !vous etes connecté'+prenom);
                responseJson.displayText = 'super ! vous etes connecté'+prenom ;
                response.json(responseJson);
            }

        });
```

but the `response.json(responseJson);` doesn't show the result

Comment: Try consoleing the responseJson if there's data in it . And though you're not getting any in response.json(). Then, you have an issue with async call. @Mim Awnaf

Comment: thank you for your reply, yes i have data when i consoleing the variable in the function , but my problem why  response.json(responseJson); doesn't work ?

Comment: Do you have a git for this. It would have been helpful if i could see the code. @Mim Awnaf

Comment: thanks,iam working on Dialogflow console